# PixHawk I/II not working in 'Rover' mode (firmware issue?).... HELP!

Tags: ros, power

We are working in a new agricultural rover, and we opted for PixHaw-II+ROS+MavLink platform as a good control alternative. However, our project is stuck as the PixHawk seems to work only when it is using Drone configuration: using Drone mode, power is released when performing drone-commands(wheels start moving). Once the configuration is changed to 'Rover' mode, there is no power output at all, even after calibrating the sensors and the battery (with this configuration, no PWM signal is shown when hooking up an oscilloscope.
We used Qgroundcontrol and Mission planner for the configuration, but none worked.

Has someone faced the same issue? we are quite sure this is a firmware-related problem. So any advice or trouble-shooting strategy is really welcome! Thank you!

Comment: Can you give us the configs, what are the differences? What works in drone mode?

Comment: Did you try disabling the sailsafe ?